# How to add some specific commits from master to another branch on git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I've this work flow with git. origin/master is 7 commits ahead of my branch "crazy-work" and crazy-work has 10 new commits. Now I want to merge crazy-work to origin/master. What is the best way to do this with minimal conflicts. even if there any conflict occurs choose the crazy-work branch's files as selected work. note that the branch crazy-work has the updated and stable source code.

Here is a little diagram

```
 origin/master ------ a --- b --- c --- d --- e --- f ----?
                             \                           /      
                              \  crazy-work             /
                               \___ h ___ i ___ j ___ k/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly merge `crazy-work` to master, or you can first *rebase* `crazy-work` to master, resolving all the conflicts, and then merge it cleanly.

Scenario 1

```
git checkout master
git merge crazy-work
```

Scenario 2

```
git checkout crazy-work
git rebase master
#  possibly fixing conflicts, followed by
#  git rebase --continue
git checkout master
git merge crazy-work
```

Comment: For solving conflicts, How do I prefer the crazy-work branch's files over master work?

Comment: You can specify `-s recursive -X theirs` to `merge`, but be very careful with that.

Comment: @SamuelRobert: Exactly. Also, human inspection is always needed after a merge, the algorithms don't really understand what's going on and can break the code, even if rarely.

Comment: I believe Linus Torvalds!. Hopefully nothing breaks.